# Covariance Matrix showing covariance between each value in vectors

Tags: python, statistics, covariance

Is there a python function that allows me to compute a n*n auto covariance matrix, displaying the covariance between each combination of the entries in a vector [a1,a2,a3...an]? I can't get np.cov to do that...
I want it to look like this:

```
    cov(a1,a1) cov(a1,a2)... cov(a1,an)
    cov(a2,a1) cov(a2,a2)...
    ...
    cov(an,a1) ...           cov(an,an)
```

Any help is appreciated!
Cheers, 
Lena

Comment: How would you compute the covariance between two elements of an array?   Numpy's `cov()` computes [sample covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance). To do that it requires 2 samples, i.e. two arrays. If you compute it using 1 element arrrays you will always get `nan` (1/(1-1) = inf), or 0 if you use the biased version with the division by N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the pandas package. 
http://pandas.pydata.org/

Dataframes have a covariance method that computes the covariances between all columns in the DataFrame.

This should roughly be the workflow.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(your_vector)
cov = df.cov()
```

Cov is now a dataframe that contains the covariences between all the columns in your vector. You can than do what ever analysis you want on the resulting dataframe.